# Bind custom object property to BooleanBinding

Tags: java, data-binding, javafx, javafx-8

Given a Java expression of type `BooleanBinding` (say `x.lessThan(y)`), what is the simplest way to bind an `ObjectProperty p` to it with a custom mapping from `boolean`?

Specifically, is there a simpler way than the following?

```
BooleanBinding b = x.lessThan(y);
p.bind(new ObjectBinding<Paint>(){
    {
        super.bind(b);
    }

    @Override
    protected Paint computeValue() {
        if(b.get()){
            return Color.BLUE;
        } else {
            return Color.RED;
        }
    }
});
```

I would have loved to do something like `p.bind(x.lessThan(y).ifElse(Color.BLUE,Color.RED))`

Comment: You mean something like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/When.html ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Bindings.when`:

```
p.bind(Bindings.when(x.lessThan(y)).then(Color.BLUE).otherwise(Color.RED));
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/When.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#when-javafx.beans.value.ObservableBooleanValue-